# require_once localhost wordpress in functions error

Tags: php, wordpress, function, require-once

Have tried most suggested answers on this topic and none seem to work for me.

I have a wordpress installed on my localhost using MAMP, now in my functions.php I am attempting the following code:

```
require_once('framework/functions/core-functions.php' );
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: require_once(framework/functions/core-functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 443

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'framework/functions/core-functions.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 443
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `require_once(__DIR__.'/framework/functions/core-functions.php');`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately the problems still persists with same warning, seems like its not registering the __DIR__. part.

Comment: Where in your filesystem is this `core-functions.php` located?. Btw, `__DIR__` is since PHP 5.3; for older versions use `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: the 'core-functions.php' is located in my themes folder, so '/themes/mytheme/framework/functions/core-functions.php' im using latest version on MAMP, so presumably the latest php

Comment: Source of the problem discovered, your first suggestion worked. The problem was I had duplicated the code in the actual php file I was trying to "pull" into my functions, hence why the same error occurred. Thanks @Kenny

Comment: Aha! Glad you got it sorted, you're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the current path to a variable first, then set the path relative to that.

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
require "$path/framework/functions/core-functions.php";
```

Comment: @MrJamesBond Then your "framework" folder is not next to the current file. Figure out where the folder is actually located and get back to us.

Comment: Hi @Pamblam, your method worked, I had duplicated the require_once into the php file I was trying to "pull" into my functions. Hence the same error occurred.

Comment: @MrJamesBond That's great news. If I helped please consider hitting that check mark by my answer.